# Write a script (or a command)

Tags: bash

I have a problem with the task:

> Write a script (or a command), that scans the whole directory structure, starting from the current directory and saves in the file /tmp/sript3.out the names (with paths) of empty regular files (of size 0). The script is allowed to check only those subdirectories, to which it has "proper" access rights (knowledge of these rights is a part of the task and no errors may be printed).

I don't know how to do it, i have tried something like:

```
for file in `ls`
do
  if [$((ls -s file)) == 0]; then
  file > /tmp/script3.out
done
```

Comment: Have a look at the `find` command.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Answer (score 2):

Try

```sh
find . -type f -size 0 > /tmp/script3.out 2>/dev/null
```

Have a look at the man page for a description of the find command. You can see one [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) - but best to look on your system (`man find`).

As for the rest:

- the "." Means start at the current directory.
- the "-size 0" Means look for things that are 0 bytes in size.
- the "-type f" Means look for regular files.
- the "> /tmp/script3.out" Means write the result to the file named /tmp/script3.out and
- the "2> /dev/null" means throw away any errors (e.g. you don't have permission to read this directory).

Comment: Add some explanation, and/or links to look stuff up for himself. ;)

Comment: Assuming this works for you, could you accept the answer please (click the little grey check mark)

Comment: @W.Dude if this has helped you, could you please accept the answer (click on the grey check mark next to the answer) and up vote it? Thanks.